# Can I retrieve a user's supervisor via the JIRA API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'd like to create a report summarizing users with unapproved time sheets, summarized by manager.  This value is stored in the system somewhere; it's exposed in the web GUI under Temp | Timesheets | User Preferences | My Supervisor.  However, I have not been able to retrieve it using REST calls such as:

```
https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences/key=mysupervisor
https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences/key=my_supervisor
https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences/key=supervisor
https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences/search?key=mysupervisor
https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences/search?key=my_supervisor
https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/mypreferences/search?key=supervisor
```

These all return a 404.  Nor does it appear in the basic `.../api/2/user/` info.

Is my structure correct to retrieve preferences?  If so, what key (if any) applies for "my supervisor"?  Finally, is there a way to retrieve this information for other users, or is it only available via *my* preferences?

[The main REST doc](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/mypreferences-getPreference) does not give a list of preference keys.

I found [a list](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/6.1/reference/com/atlassian/jira/user/preferences/PreferenceKeys.html?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.atlassian.com%2Fstatic%2Fjavadoc%2Fjira%2F6.1%2Freference%2Fcom%2Fatlassian%2Fjira%2Fuser%2Fpreferences%2FPreferenceKeys.html&application=dac) of preference keys, but "supervisor" does not appear.  Also, using the keys in the REST calls above still returns 404s.

I'm using JIRA 6.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the manager is a custom field in your jira set up.

What you need to do is find the custom field id of your manager/supervisor. Run this in a browser

```
https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/field
```

This will give you ALL of the fields you have defined and have access to. Do a search for the field you are looking for. ONce you have the id of the field, you can create a jql that gives you your result

Comment: That's a handy reference, thanks.  Unfortunately, no, there's no "manager" or "supervisor" custom field.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more :( I've never experienced a work hierarchy stored in Jira. Its possible this is coming from the LDAP that JIra uses. I also don't have a Temp | Timesheets  menu in my JIra. Its possible this is some plugin that you're using? If so, I'm guessing using the generic JIra REST APi you can't get the supervisor info